# How to report people terrorizing the lobby

Tags: dota-2

The lobby of Dota2 is one big pile of vomit, i always see someone get flamed or extremely sick comments. I rarely participate in the chat but whenever i do feel the need of saying something in the chat my mother pretty much gets the hot topic award. Racism, extremely harsh language, flaming, bullying they are going on 24/7 in the lobby of Dota 2. I have seen chat boxes close for less, a lot less.

Whenever i feel bored waiting for a game i put people on ignore but this does not seem to help at all. Is there any way i can report people so proper action can be taken against them?

Comment: i do not really understand your situation. are you using the chatrooms on the right side or are you talking about actual lobbies?
In both cases i would recommend leaving the chat/lobby and joining another. Is that no option?

Comment: @wandang Im talking about the chat inside the lobby.  I have tried several public chats all pretty much the same.  Of course joining an empty channel fixes this.  But these trolling idiots should not have a free platform for harassing people.

Comment: Afaik there is no option to report people outside of a game.

Comment: @Wandang That is very poor of valve, isn't it manitory to monitor behaviour of users on your network? I mean there are a lot of kids on it and the stuff i read there shocks even me sometimes.

Comment: You should go to http://dev.dota2.com/ and post your suggestion there. I agree that pure hatred should not be tolerated but it is no high priority for valve right now. If there are severe cases you can always report a player via steam community: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1476-HJCM-5616

Comment: I don't think I've ever joined a public chat, because this is exactly what I'd expect from one of the harshest gaming communities I've experienced. Although it isn't a solution, I would recommend not joining public chat rooms at all.

Comment: Why would you even join any chatroom? Isn't the in-game sh*t-ism enough? Play with friends, if not, just add people with whom you had a good time.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for this previously, and **no**, there is no way to report them at the moment. I do hope this feature will be implemented soon.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you cannot report people who abuse in the lobby. But you can ignore them by clicking their name and choose "Ignore Player".

This is a great idea you should post your idea/suggestions at http://dev.dota2.com/. Though I think they will most likely not implement this before every other things is settled.